Allow user "kids" to access only wikipedia
I did
iptables -I OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner kids -d www.wikipedia.org -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner kids -d www.wikipedia.org -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner kids -j REJECT

and same with ip6tables
I then have:
iptables -S
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d 208.80.154.224/32 -p tcp -m owner --uid-owner 1001 -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d 208.80.154.224/32 -p tcp -m owner --uid-owner 1001 -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner 1001 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

However, all access is blocked, including to wikipedia.  Presumably, I need to give access to other websites as well?

Wikipedia (as almost every other big website) uses multiple different IP addresses. They can change over time. You need to include all of them in your firewall rules. It may be however not easy to actually get to know all of them.
Maybe a browser-based approach when you allow only the Wikipedia domain (not IP address) would be better. You can use some browser extension for it, or eg. use a PAC file that proxies traffic to all other domains through some non-existent proxy.

you should list all the IP wikipedia use, accept then all, and also allow DNS output for them to resolve. (I would do the limitation with a proxy and some squidguard)

You may find this helpful, in particular it discusses the importance of rule order and suggests adding a rule for ESTABLISHED,RELATED traffic and an explicit rule for  DNS lookup: iptables rules to allow HTTP traffic to one domain only

This might be an XY Problem. The actual problem is children's curiosity and a filthy, filthy internet. Your preferred solution will be labor-intensive and perhaps unsatisfying. Children, like all humans, are very, very good at finding loopholes and workarounds.
